# For statement rendering icon on Shopify

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, shopify, assign, nested-for-loop

I have a blog section on my website and I'd like to render an icon of new post on top of the blog image but only for the first 3 blogs posts.

I tried to do the following:

> {% for article in blogs.news.articles limit: 3 %}
>
> {% render 'llp-icons' icon: 'new-post' %}

And this code is placing the icon in every single blog post. The limit 3 is not working ( I thought that would limit redenring the icon only on the three first posts) however this **for loop** would be nested *within another* for loop so I understand that is why is not working, because is nested.

So I thought that if I {%assign%} a variable to the icon, and create an if statement to place that variable only in the first three blog posts, that would work. However I am kind of lost how to make the If statement. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this maybe this will help

```
{% for article in blogs.news.articles %}
 {% if forloop.index < 3 %}
  {% render 'llp-icons' icon: 'new-post' %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or you can use capture like this

```
{%- capture icon_code -%}
  {% render 'llp-icons' icon: 'new-post' %}
{%- endcapture -%}
{% for article in blogs.news.articles %}
 {% if forloop.index < 3 %}
  {{ icon_code }}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks @hamza, I tried it as well however it is still rendering in every single blog post. I think I realised I need to assign a variable to the icon and pass it in an If statement however I don't know how to assign the icon to the variable :(

Comment: @vthelamb you can use capture for that like this `{%- capture icon_code -%}{% render 'llp-icons' icon: 'new-post' %}{%- endcapture -%}`